# Caching (Caffeine) & Spring - two caches based on method parameter value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

I have a question about caching in spring using Caffeine.

I have a cache configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class CaffeineCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager(
                "someDataCache1",
                "someDataCache2");
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(100)
                .maximumSize(200)
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .recordStats();
    }

}
```

And a `@Cachaeble` method:

```
@Override
@Cacheable
public List<SomeData> getSomeData(String group) {
    return someService.getSomeDataForGroup(group);
}
```

Now, the `group` values are predefined, they can only be `group1`, `group2` and `group3` will be added in the future.

Can this caching mechanism be configured basing on `String group` value, so `someDataCache1` will be used when `String group` will be `group1` and `someDataCache1` will be used when `String group` is `group2` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple [conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#condition--) [`@Cacheable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) annotations to the [`@Caching`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Caching.html) annotation.

```java
@Caching(cacheable = {
        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "someDataCache1", condition = "#group.equals('group1')"),
        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "someDataCache2", condition = "#group.equals('group2')")
})
public List<String> getSomeData(String group) {
    return someService.getSomeDataForGroup(group);
}
```